# Building using Makefile: picks file.c instead of file.cpp even though specified explicitly

Tags: c++, c, makefile

**Abstract:**

I have a .c file and a .cpp file with the same name in the same parent folder. I no longer wish to compile the .c file but doesn't want to remove it from the folder too.

Even though I explicitly specify to compile the .cpp file, the makefile was making use of the .c file. How can I fix this issue?

On renaming *file3.c* to another name, *file3.cpp* gets compiled.

**Details:**

The files present in '*src*' folder are:

```
file1.c
file2.c
file3.c
file3.cpp
file4.cpp
```

Important extracts from the makefile:

```
SOURCE_FILES := ./src/file1.c \
        ./src/file2.c \
        ./src/file3.cpp \
        ./src/file4.cpp

OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(filter %.cpp, $(SOURCE_FILES))) \
    $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(filter %.c, $(SOURCE_FILES)))

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(PROJECT).bin $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) 

.cpp.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
    @echo 'CPP FILE : ' $<

.c.o:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
    @echo 'C FILE : ' $<
```

On doing 'make', the log of the echo command gives:

```
C FILE : ./src/file1.c
C FILE : ./src/file2.c
C FILE : ./src/file3.c
CPP FILE : ./src/file4.cpp
```

**Questions:**

1. How can the above issue be solved?
2. Is there an easier way to fetch values for my *OBJS* variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `make` uses to pick which of two possible matching rules gets used depends on which version of `make` you are using. (It changed between 3.81 and 3.82 and I believe got tweaked slightly for 4.0+ but am not certain about that.)

I believe make 3.81 used the last matching rule and make 3.82+ uses the matching rule with the shortest stem (the bit that matches the `%`) and then the first matching rule between rules that have similar stem lengths.

So it would seem like you are using make 3.81 currently.

In that case it should be possible to simply swap the order of your two rules to get the behavior you want (assuming you always want `.cpp` files to "win").

Alternatively you could try giving make an *explicit* prerequisite for the `file3.o` target instead of letting it guess. (i.e. `file3.o: file3.cpp`)

That said neither of your explicit suffix rules is necessary as make already contains default rules to build `.o` files from both `.c` and `.cpp` files. (I don't know the relative ordering between them so you likely will need the explicit prerequisite, assuming that works, for the built-in rules to work correctly.)

Also you might want to look at using [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) instead of [Old-Fashioned Suffix Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules) just as a point of current practice.

The only improvement to your populating the `OBJS` variable that I can see, offhand, is to filter on the results and so just filter once.

```
OBJS = $(filter %.o,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCE_FILES)) \
    $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCE_FILES)))
```

That said you could also use [Substitution References](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) instead of explicit calls to `$(patsubst)` to shorten that a bit.

```
OBJS = $(filter %.o,$(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o) $(SOURCE_FILES:.c=.o))
```

Comment: Like you assumed to be, I am using make 3.81. Changing the ordering of didn't help the issue. But changing the 'Old-fashioned Suffix Rule' to 'Pattern Rules' helped the issue to be solved. :) The shortened way of writing OBJS was also very helpful.

Comment: Removing my 'explicit suffix rules' was leading to not finding the header files. Is there a way to fix this issue while removing the explicit suffix rules?

Comment: You can supply your own flags to the built-in rules. See [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for the list and what variables they use. You can also see the output of `make -p` for the list specific to your build/version of `make`. The matching rules behavior I mentioned is listed for pattern rules specifically. I assumed it might also apply to suffix rules but do not know that for certain.

Comment: Irrespective of the order, pattern rule picks the correct file. I guess that rule comes into action if I try compiling both file3.c and file3.cpp together.

Comment: No, the rules should affect exactly this situation. How to match a target against a set of pattern rules. The output from `make -d` might contain insight into what make is doing (and whether the order changes how make tries things).

Comment: Thank you. Your responses and links have been very very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have rules for both .c ==> .o and .cpp ==> .o.
In your case the rule for file3.c is run first since the newly created file3.o file now exists. Since the target file3.o file exists, there is no reason to compile file3.cpp.

Looking [at the make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html), if there are 2 rules for the same target, the last rule is used.

Comment: I am not asking the makefile to run it on file3.c. Then how come that is being called?

Comment: Yes you were, you work out what the .o file targets you need from a pattern rule. As far as make is concerned, this is a simple pattern match. Once we know the .o files requires, we look for any rule that can create said .o file.

Comment: The question was *why* is the `.c.o` rule being seen first (and used) and how to get make to use the `.cpp.o` rule first instead. make will absolutely **not** try to use two rules to create the same file *ever*. That's not how make works.