# makefile patsubst multiple expressions

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to simplify some of my makefiles, and i started doing this:

```
TEMP_OBJECTS_C = $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(C_SOURCES)) 
TEMP_OBJECTS_CPP = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(CPP_SOURCES))
```

but what i really wanted to do, is simply append .o to anything that ends in .c or .cpp. This will only work for .c, if i want to add cpp files, i have to make a completely separate substitution.
I tried this:

```
TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(SOURCES)) $(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(SOURCES))
```

with SOURCES being all cpp and c files, but then i obviously got duplicate files, and the original source filenames in it...

So, i went with this:

```
TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(SOURCES))
TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(TEMP_OBJECTS))
```

but then it complained about recursivity.

Is there any way to make what i need?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To paraphrase from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737691/258523).

Use `$(filter)` to include only the entries you that you want.

```
OBJS = $(filter %.o,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(CPP_SOURCES)) \
    $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(C_SOURCES)))
```

That said you could also use [Substitution References](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) instead of explicit calls to $(patsubst) to shorten that a bit.

```
OBJS = $(filter %.o,$(CPP_SOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o))
```

If you wanted to keep your original final attempt then you just need to make your variable simply-expanded instead of recursively-expanded (see [The Two Flavors of Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) for more explanation of this difference).

```
TEMP_OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(SOURCES))
TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(TEMP_OBJECTS))
```

Comment: Probably going to use this one. Was simply trying to find a way to trim down the line count on my makefile, and to avoid temporary variables and such...

Comment: I think the last example has the flavors reversed; as written it would still complain about recursion. The `:=` should be on the second line and the `=` on the first.

Answer (score 0):

I would try
`TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(SOURCES)))`

or something like:

```
TEMP_OBJECTS_C = $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(SOURCES))
TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(TEMP_OBJECTS_C))
```

Both are pretty the same and will filter the sources twice.

or the anser which was given already:

```
TEMP_OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(SOURCES))
TEMP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(TEMP_OBJECTS))
```

The `:=` will immediately evaluate the expression thus avoiding recursion.